# React data from useState is not updating in console.log

Tags: reactjs

Why `data` is not updated in `handleKeyUp()` in `console.log()`?
It renders just fine but it's not updating in `console.log()`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    index: 0,
    lastChar: null
  });

  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    console.log(data);

    setData((current) => {
      return {
        index: current.index + 1,
        lastChar: e.key
      };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => handleKeyUp(e));

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.index}
      {data.lastChar}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Put console.log outside of the handleKeyUp function and check

Answer (score 0):

You're logging **data** before it's being set by setData

```js
 const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    // log data
    console.log(data);
    // set data
    setData((current) => {
      return {
        index: current.index + 1,
        lastChar: e.key
      };
    });
  };
```

Then you have a useEffect which only fires when the component mounts (because of the empty dependancy array)

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => handleKeyUp(e));
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    };
  }, []);
```

You can move your `console.log` to after your useEffect and you'll see the updated value of **data**

```js
  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    setData((current) => {
      return {
        index: current.index + 1,
        lastChar: e.key
      };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => handleKeyUp(e));
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    };
  }, []);

    console.log(data);

  return (
...
```

Answer (score 0):

your useEffect is doing error here,consider your current code

```
useEffect(() => {
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => handleKeyUp(e));

return () => {
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
};
}, []);
```

above code will have older reference to handleKeyup which is need to be updated every time handleKey up is updated ,now inorder to do it , you will need to add handleKey up as a dependency of useEffect like this

```
useEffect(() => {
document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => handleKeyUp(e));

return () => {
  document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
};
}, [handleKeyUp]);
```

right now on each render your handleKeyUp will be defined , in order to prevent it you can make use of useCallback hook like this

```
const handleKeyUp =useCallback( (e) => {
console.log(data);

setData((current) => {
  return {
    index: current.index + 1,
    lastChar: e.key
  };
});
},[setData,data]);
```

hope it will help